# Cypress and contexts - wait for context

Tags: timing, cypress

I have diveded my cypress script into two separate contexts like this:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

context('Navigation', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
cy.visit('xxx')
cy.get('.form-group:first-child input:nth-child(1)')
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        cy.wrap($el).type('xxx')
        break;
      case 1:
        cy.wrap($el).type('xxx')
        break;
      case 2:
        cy.wrap($el).type('xxx') // CUSTOMER_ID
        break;
    }
  });
cy.get('button').contains('Søg').click()
})

it('Meld skade', () => {
// TODO
})

});

context('Check CRM', () => {
it('Calling API directly', () =>{
cy
  .request('http://xxx')
  .its('body')
  .should('include', 'Api is alive')
})
})
```

When running it, it does not wait for the first context to finish up before starting the second.
How can I make sure the first context is run compleltly before starting contex #2?

Comment: I would suggest wrapping them in an outer describe/context.